# Modercv Banking: one university multiple degrees

Tags: moderncv

I am making a CV and am looking to achieve a look like this:

```
 University 1

 Degree 1                     Jan 2016 -- Present
 Details about degree 1
 Degree 2                     Previous -- Jan 2016
 Details about degree 2

 University 2  Degree X
 Details about degree X
```

At the moment, I have the following code which requires me to enter the same university twice. If I do not enter it the second time, there is just a blank line. The same could apply for different job titles at different employers.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{banking} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Windows 

\firstname{Student}
\familyname{of Master}
%\title{Dragonkin}         
\address{70 x street}{xxxx}   
\mobile{+61 xxx xxx xxx}    

\email{x@latex.com}           
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multibib,comment}
\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

\nopagenumbers{}                         
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{-0.09em}%Change space between entries

%%%%%%Change space between sections

\maketitle

\vspace{-1.3cm}

\section{Education}

\cventry{{2016--Present}}{Postgraduate degree}{University of Gauss}{Antarctica}{}{Details about degree}

\cventry{{2011--2015}}{Undergraduate degree}{University of Gauss}
{Antarctica}{}{Details}

\cventry{{2006--2010}}{High school certificate}{High School}{London}{}{details
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the theme is not that flexible.
A simple patch is to define your own command based on the original definition of `\cventry` for this theme.

```
\newcommand*{\cvsimple}[4][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
    % {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#4&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#4%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

With this definition in place you can write

```
\cventry{{2016--Present}}{Postgraduate degree}{University of Gauss}{Antarctica}{}{Details about degree}
\cvsimple{{2016--Present}}{Postgraduate degree}{Details about degree}
```

to obtain what you wanted.

Here's the full modified code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{banking} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Windows 

\firstname{Student}
\familyname{of Master}
%\title{Dragonkin}         
\address{70 x street}{xxxx}   
\mobile{+61 xxx xxx xxx}    

\email{x@latex.com}           
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\newcommand*{\cvsimple}[4][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
    % {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#4&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#4%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multibib,comment}
\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

\nopagenumbers{}                         
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{-0.09em}%Change space between entries

%%%%%%Change space between sections

\maketitle

\vspace{-1.3cm}

\section{Education}

\cventry{{2016--Present}}{Postgraduate degree}{University of Gauss}{Antarctica}{}{Details about degree}
\cvsimple{{2016--Present}}{Postgraduate degree}{Details about degree}


\cventry{{2011--2015}}{Undergraduate degree}{University of Gauss}
{Antarctica}{}{Details}

\cventry{{2006--2010}}{High school certificate}{High School}{London}{}{details
}

\end{document}
```

## Details

The definition of `\cvsimple` above is based on the definition of `\cventry` used by the banking theme, which, confusingly, is contained in the file `moderncvbodyiii.sty`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```